# How to communicate port from grunt connect to grunt jasmine task

Tags: jasmine, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I am using grunt connect (`"grunt-contrib-connect": "0.11.2"`) in conjunction with grunt jasmine (`"grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^1.1.0"`). The connect config was previously hardcoding the port number and the jasmine config was also configured to use the same port number in the `host` config option.

I now want to enable the `useAvailablePort` option in connect in order to resolve an issue with concurrent builds using the same port. However I am struggling to understand how to correctly communicate the port number from connect to jasmine?

Here are the relevant sections of my grunt init config block:

```js
connect: {
  test: {
    options: {
      keepalive: false,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: 1234,
      base: ['.']
    }
  }
}
```

```js
jasmine: {
  js: {
    src: ...,
    options: {
      keepRunner: true,
      summary: true,
      host: 'http://localhost:1234/',
      specs: 'src/test/js/**/*Spec.js',
      vendor: ...
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a grunt test task using:

```js
grunt.registerTask('test', ['connect', 'jasmine:js']);
```

So what would be the best practice way of capturing the port from `connect` and setting the host in `jasmine:js`?

I have been trying to change the test task as follows, but with no joy (also not sure if this would be the correct way to do it):

```js
grunt.registerTask('test', 'Run jasmine unit tests', function () {
  grunt.event.once('connect.test.listening', function(host, port) {
    var jasmineHost = 'http://' + host + ':' + port;
    grunt.log.writeln('Running jasmine tests from: ' + jasmineHost );
    grunt.config.set('jasmine:js:options:host', jasmineHost );
    grunt.task.run('jasmine:js');
  });
  grunt.task.run('connect:test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The GruntJS framework includes [lodash templates](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template), which you can use in your configs & tasks to inject values at runtime.   The documentation can be a little confusing; to solve your problem we'll add a lodash template tag within the string for `jasmine.js.options.host` & reference the other config value using json notation:

```js
jasmine: {
  js: {
    src: ...,
    options: {
      keepRunner: true,
      summary: true,
      host: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.test.port %>/',
      specs: 'src/test/js/**/*Spec.js',
      vendor: ...
    }
  }
}
```

During runtime, grunt will process the lodash template tag before executing the task.